# Using imminent job offer to goose others

Tags: interviewing, job-offer, relocation

I have several hooks in the water right now in terms of a new job.

Some of these opportunities pay extremely well but require relocation, which I am loathe to do because I don't want to uproot my kids.  Some others pay a bit less, but don't require relocation.

My preference is the lower-paying "non-relocation" jobs that allow me to stay put, but these employers are moving rather slowly through the hiring process.  I believe that I am much closer to getting an offer for one of the higher-paying "relocation" jobs.

Trying to think of if, when and how I should leverage this imminent "relocation" offer to spur the employers with the "non-relocation" jobs into moving forward.  I don't want to wait until I have an offer in hand, because "relocation" company will probably want an answer within a matter of 24 hours.  I won't have time to get the ball rolling again with the "non-relocation" employers and get a competing offer from them in time.

Basically, I want to politely/deferentially tell "non-relocation" employer "Look, I really want to join your team and I think I'd do a fantastic job, and I don't want to rush you or ask you to compromise your hiring process, but I have an offer that will be heading my way very soon, and I need to know where I stand with you all so I can make an informed decision about how to proceed."

Maybe I just say exactly that?  But then I worry I'll just push them into disengaging instead of moving the ball forward.

Would be grateful for thoughts and insight on how one might play this, or how it's been played successfully in the past.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's duplicates of this question ...

Comment: Just be careful as you may end up with no job at all

Comment: Thanks, folks.  Jane S. - yes, very similar circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see that you're under any obligation to respond to an offer in 24 hours, especially for a job that requires relocation. You can tell them something along the lines of "As this is a big step, I do need to discuss it with my family first, surely you understand. Because I don't count my chickens before they're hatched, only my spouse [if you have one] knows that I've been looking at several out-of-town opportunities. Can I have a few days to talk it over?"

As to the other part, I don't think it's inappropriate to call and ask where things are in the process. You can then let them know that you do have other irons in the fire.

Sure, they might disengage as a result but I wouldn't want to work for a company that rejects a candidate because they're looking at more than one place. If they can't handle a little competition, they've got other issues.

Comment: Great thoughts.  Thank you.  I guess if they disengage over something like that, I probably wasn't a super-strong contender anyway.

Answer (score 2):

If you have or are expecting competing offers, it's generally a good idea to let the other parties know. You don't necessarily need to share the details - some companies may try to pry information about the other companies or what they are offering and you probably don't need to share that information. Some companies may decide to disengage, while others may try to speed up the process. It depends on their situation and what they think of you as a candidate.

However, I'd be cautious of any company that expects an response to an offer in 24 hours. I would expect any company to give you at least several days to review an offer, ask any clarifying questions that you have, and consider those answers. They may not want a long, drawn out back-and-forth conversation, but changing jobs may be a big deal, especially if relocation is necessary.

Comment: Thanks much.  As for the 24-hour thing, that may have been a wee bit of an exaggeration, but not by much.  Given what this job pays and the fact that they are laying all cards on the table, once the offer hits, there really isn't anything in the way of new information to consider.

Whether it's 24 hours or one week, my fear is that it's still not enough time to spur any of the other employers to make a proper offer.